# How to show icon in toolbar instead of text

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-menu, android-icons

I am trying to show some icons in the toolbar using the following menu but in the output Instead of icons, only text is displaying. How to display icons instead of text

menu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/toEditName"
            android:title="@string/buttonEditName"
            app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
            tools:icon="@drawable/ic_edit_name" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/toHistory"
            android:title="@string/buttonHistory"
            app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
            tools:icon="@drawable/ic_history" />
    </menu>
```

[Preview Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vQRRL.png)

[Actual Output Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MrdzM.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `android:icon` attribute not `tools:icon` Try this

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/toEditName"
        android:title="@string/buttonEditName"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_edit_name" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/toHistory"
        android:title="@string/buttonHistory"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_history" />
</menu>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your icons are not displayed because you are using tools attribute, which show the icon when you are working in the android studio. If you run the app the icons are not displayed.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
         <item
             android:id="@+id/toEditName"
             android:icon="@drawable/ic_edit_name"
             android:title="@string/buttonEditName"
             app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
         <item
             android:id="@+id/toHistory"
             android:icon="@drawable/ic_history"
             android:title="@string/buttonHistory"
             app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
      </menu>
```

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

it was a bit late, but tools attribute usually is used to display something in your Android Studio xml preview. That is why your icon not showing.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">


    <item
        android:id="@+id/multi_select_reply"
        android:title="@string/reply"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_reply_svg"   <--- change tools:icon to android:icon
        android:iconTint="@color/colorWhite"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>

</menu>
```

Hope it helps to you!